# Converting an equation into a quadratic polynomial in terms of time

Tags: quadratics, collision-detection

I was trying to do some collision detection between discs for a physics simulation program I was doing. I had arrived at the equation:

Object1Coordinate + (time$\cdot$Object1Velocity) = Object2Coordinate + (Time$\cdot$Object2Velocity)

I gave this to a friend to help me turn this into an equation where I could solve for time.

He came up with:

($t^2$)(magnitude of vector between the two velocities$)^2 + 2t$(dot product between the coordinates and velocities delta) + (magnitude of vector of the difference between the two coordinates)$^2$

How did he get to this quadratic formula?

I'm sorry for the bad formatting, I don't know how to use the math notation. If anyone would like to help me format the question properly I would be thankful

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Typically collision detection is done in multidimensional space, so that the object coordinates and velocities are vector valued.  I actually don't think that the equation you want to solve requires a quadratic polynomial.

Comment: Its on a 2D coordinate Cartesian plane. The quadratic works I just wanted to know how he arrived on that equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your friend likely started with the vector equation:
$$ \Delta x + t \Delta v = \vec 0, $$
where $\Delta x$ is the (vector) difference of coordinates and $\Delta v$ is the difference of velocities, then used the fact that $\vec v = \vec 0$ iff $\|\vec v\|^2 = \vec v \cdot \vec v = 0$, so the equation is equivalent to
$$(\Delta x + t \Delta v)\cdot(\Delta x + t \Delta v) =  (\Delta x \cdot \Delta x) + 2t (\Delta x \cdot \Delta v) + t^2 (\Delta v \cdot \Delta v)\\
 =  \|\Delta x\|^2 +  2t (\Delta x \cdot \Delta v) + t^2 \|\Delta v\|^2 = 0.$$

However, it makes little sense to literally solve this equation as written (I notice that the OP doesn't actually specify that the RHS is zero): as hardmath points out a quadratic is not really necessary since by geometric considerations the quadratic is either strictly positive (if there is no intersection), or it has a double-root at the unique solution (with one exception: if $\Delta v = \Delta x = \vec 0$ then it's identically zero), so solving the quadratic directly is silly.

However, finding the unique **critical point** of the quadratic corresponds to minimizing the distance between the two objects.  That value of $t_c = -\|\Delta v\|^2 / (\Delta x \cdot \Delta v)$ is the least-squares approximate solution to the overconstrained system $\Delta x + t \Delta v = \vec 0$.

Comment: Could you give me a step by step on how it got to the quadratic?

Comment: The RHS is actually the sum of the radii of the two objects squared. I want to solve for t as it represents the time of collision which I can then resolve

Comment: @bi0phaz3 Ah, that makes sense, then there could be two solutions for $t$ geometrically (the entry time of collision and the exit time).  The long equation in my answer already is essentially a step-by-step: the key is that the distance between the centers of the two objects is equal to the length of $\Delta x + t \Delta v$.  To compute the (squared) length of a vector, you take its dot product with itself, and that's exactly the computation above.